# Date Convert in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need DD-MM-YYYY Format of the given date.

```
var todaydate = /Date(1394908200000)/; //Serialize date
var date = eval("new " + todaydate.replace(/\//g, ""));
alert('date is :'+date)
```

but output look like,

```
date is :Wed Jun 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Expected output like,

```
date is :11-06-2014
```

Comment: so you have the `timestamp`/`long date` format as input?

Comment: Looks like you're working with an odata returned date.. if that's the case, then save yourself some time and just include moment.js in your project. It understands those dates and provides exceptional formatting functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides of JS like other people mention, you can also use the `.datepicker` from [jquery ui plug-in](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
var dt = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date(1394908200000));

alert(dt);
```

[JSFiddle, use jquery ui plug-in](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/Htew5/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
var date = new Date(); //new Date(1394908200000)
function convert(str) {
    var date = new Date(str),
        mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return [day, mnth, date.getFullYear()].join("-");
}

var final = convert(date);
alert('date is :' + final)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/12/)

Answer (score 1):

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/21/)

Try this-

```
var date = new Date();

function myDateFormatter (dateobject) {
    var d = new Date(dateobject);
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    var date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

    return date;
}; 
var dateformat = myDateFormatter(date);
alert('date is :' + dateformat);
```